# Perform Aggregations using JSON1 and SQLite3 in Json Objects

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite-json1

I just started using SQLite 3 with JSON1 support.

I already have created a database that consists of several attributes.
One of these attributes is a json object.

What I want to do is perform aggregations within this object.

Running the following query:

```
select json_extract(report, '$.some_attribute')
from table1
group by var1
having date == max(date);
```

returns the following:

```
[{"count":55,"label":"A"},{"count":99,"label":"B"}, {"count":1,"label":"C"}]
[{"count":29,"label":"A"},{"count":285,"label":"B"},{"count":461,"label":"C"}]
[{"count":6642,"label":"A"},{"count":24859,"label":"B"},{"count":3031,"label":"C"}]
[{"count":489,"label":"A"},{"count":250,"label":"B"},{"count":74,"label":"C"}]
```

Now, what I want to do is to group by the **label** key and for example, **sum** the **count** key.

The output should be something like this:

```
[{"label": A, 'count': 7215},
 {"label": B, 'count': 25493},
 {"label": C, 'count': 3567}]
```

OR this:

```
  A,       B,     C
7215,    25493,  3567
```

I've tried to implement the latter one like this:

```
select sum(A) as A, sum(B) as B, sum(C) as C
from (
select json_extract(report,
                '$.some_attribute[0].count') as A,
       json_extract(report,
                '$.some_attribute[1].count') as B,
       json_extract(report,
                '$.some_attribute[0].count') as C
from table1
group by var1
having date == max(date));
```

The thing is, how can you be sure that all the objects in the array will be sorted the same way. So this may cause problems.

Any solutions? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you "un-nest"  the json strings returned from the first `json_extract`,as with [json_each](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach), it becomes trivial. This worked in my repro:

```
WITH result as (select jsonString from jsonPlay)
select json_extract(value,'$.label') label,SUM(json_extract(value,'$.count'))
from result,json_each(jsonString) 
group by label
```

Giving this result:

```
 A| 7215
 B| 25493
 C| 3567
```

Basically, your `select json_extract(report, '$.some_attribute')` block replaces `select jsonString from jsonPlay`

You could use this to "columnize" it, as in your OR option.

```
WITH result as (select jsonString from jsonPlay) 
select SUM(CASE WHEN json_extract(value,'$.label')='A' then json_extract(value,'$.count') END) 'A', 
SUM(CASE WHEN json_extract(value,'$.label')='B' then json_extract(value,'$.count') END) 'B', 
SUM(CASE WHEN json_extract(value,'$.label')='C' then json_extract(value,'$.count') END) 'C'
from result,json_each(jsonString)
```